# Android app doesn't launch in simulator or hardware

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

My app used to run, but lately I've been getting this odd error:

```
#  guarantee(_name_index != 0 && _signature_index != 0) failed: bad constant pool index for fieldDescriptor
```

How can I get my app to run in the simulator or on my phone again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was accidentally running it as a Java app instead of an Android app. My bad. Don't make my mistake young grasshoppers.